# How do I call inputs and buttons in my EmberJS acceptance tests?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, acceptance-testing

This is maddening, as there is little to no help on google/the internet for this.  https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/testing/acceptance/ is also not very helpful, even though it tries.  I am basically learning this from scratch.  I know a modest amount of HTML, handlebars, and javascript, but emphasis on the modest.

Here is my template, much of it is copied code from my architect's design who doesn't have time to help me :

```
<form {{action "login" on="submit"}} class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    {{#if loginFailed}}
    <div class="alert">Invalid username or password.</div>
  {{/if}}

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
    {{input value=username type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email"}}
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    {{input value=password type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password"}}
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled={{isProcessing}}>Log in!</button>
</form>
```

Note the application runs correctly (I'm able to generate a login screen which connects to my local database, and I am able to log in correctly when the credentials are correct and not login when they aren't).

There is also a large .js file for the route which has an ajax call and corresponding promise from it, which I can sort of understand, but bottom line, it works :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

    loginFailed: false,
  isProcessing: false,

    beforeModel: function(){
        this.store.unloadAll('security-setting');
        this.store.unloadAll('org');

        var user = this.modelFor('application').user;
        user.setProperties({email: '', auth: ''});
    },

  actions: {
    login: function() {
        this.setProperties({
          loginFailed: false,
          isProcessing: true
        });
        var _this = this;

        ajax({
            url: _this.modelFor('application').url + '/signin.json/',
            type: 'post',
            data: {session: {email: this.controller.get("username"), password: this.controller.get("password")}},
      }).then(
                function(result) {
                  // proprietary stuff, it all works
                },
                function(error){
                    alert(error.jqXHR.responseText);
                    this.set('isProcessing', false);
                _this.set("loginFailed", true);
                }
            );


      },
  },

  reset: function() {
    this.set('isProcessing', false);
    this.controller.set('password', '');
    this.controller.set('username', '');
  }
});
```

Here is the acceptance test I am trying to write :

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';
import startApp from 'ember-super-user/tests/helpers/start-app';

module('Acceptance | login', {
  beforeEach: function() {
    this.application = startApp();
  },

  afterEach: function() {
    Ember.run(this.application, 'destroy');
  }
});

test('visiting /login and fail a login attempt', function(assert) {
  visit('/login');
  fillIn('input.username', 'insert-username-here');
  fillIn('input.password', 'insert-password-here');
  click('button.submit');

  // I know this assert is wrong but I haven't even gotten this far yet so I'm     // not thinking about it; basically what happens is a popup appears and says    // wrong-username-or-password-etc
  andThen(function() {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/login');
  });
});
```

Execution dies on the `fillIn` lines of code.  I really don't know what to do here, I've tried all combinations of 'input.username', 'input.inputEmail1', 'input.inputEmail'... I'm just not sure what I'm supposed to do, at all.  I'm also pretty sure that 'button.submit' will not just magically work either.  Then, I know I'll be even more lost when I try to fill in the `andThen` promise to acknowledge the fact that a popup appeared saying wrong-password-etc.

Please help; thanks very much for your time.

EDIT: I have been able to fix the `fillIn` parts of the test, but the `click` (probably the click, anyway, as the error messages are unclear as to which line is the problem) is producing some errors that I am unable to diagnose.  Error messages appear in the output of the QUnit test suites that don't make sense to me --

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined@ 4286 ms
Expected:   
true
Result:     
false
Diff:   
trufalse
 at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:3592:13
    at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.exception (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:52460:7)
    at onerrorDefault (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:43162:24)
    at Object.exports.default.trigger (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:67346:11)
    at Promise._onerror (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68312:22)
    at publishRejection (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:66619:15)
```

EDIT 2: The latest change for changing 'button' to 'submit' still doesn't work.  Current error message :

```
Error: Element input[type='submit'] not found.@ 166 ms
Expected:   
true
Result:     
false
Diff:   
trufalse
Source:     
    at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:3592:13
    at exports.default._emberTestingAdaptersAdapter.default.extend.exception (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:52460:7)
    at onerrorDefault (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:43162:24)
    at Object.exports.default.trigger (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:67346:11)
    at Promise._onerror (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:68312:22)
    at publishRejection (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:66619:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector for each input is wrong. Since you gave each one an id, you can do this:

```
fillIn('#inputEmail1', 'insert-username-here');
fillIn('#inputPassword', 'insert-password-here');
```

Remember that you are using CSS selectors for the first argument of `fillIn`, IDs use `#` prefix and classes use `.`.

For the submit button, you did not add a class or ID, but if it is the only submit button on the page you can target it like this:

```
click('button[type="submit"]');
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am now getting a new error though : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.set').  I also tried giving the button an id "submitButton" and then using that in the same manner as the fillIns, but same error occurred.

Comment: My hunch is that it is unrelated to the test and more to do with your application code. I would try seeing which line is throwing that error and the stack trace it produces.

Comment: you might be right, although the stack trace is nonsensical to me, I don't know how it could lead me to where the error is.  It's pretty maddening considering other programming languages give you pretty clear stack traces on where errors occur.  Any further help would be great -- thanks.

Comment: There are a few errors I see after scanning your code. You are trying to directly access `var user = this.modelFor('application').user;`, it should be `var user = this.modelFor('application').get('user');` In your error handler you have `this.set('isProcessing', false);`, it should be `_this.set...`. If you use chrome devtools you can make it break on caught errors, check the async checkbox, and explore a fuller stack trace to see where it's try to call `set`.

Answer (score 1):

The fillIn and click functions takes in css selectors. so for example, clicking on the submit would look like,

```
click("input[type='submit']");
```

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work either.  Check edits on the question for the error message; thanks.

Comment: my mistake, should be button[type='submit']